# Localization of enum in Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, enums, localization, thymeleaf

In a form I have radio buttons that correspond to an enum:

```
public enum EleType {
    INTEGER, 
    CHARACTER
}
```

The html of the form is:

```
<div class="form-check" th:each="elementType : ${T(org.example.sorting.EleType).values()}">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="elemType" th:id="${{elementType}}" th:field="*{elementType}" th:value="${{elementType}}" />
    <label th:for="${{elementType}}"  th:text="${{elementType}}">Elem Types</label>
</div>
```

This gives me radio buttons with labels "INTEGER", "CHARACTER".

I would like to translate these strings using the messages.properties file. So with `label.pages.sorting.INTEGER=Integer` and `label.pages.sorting.CHARACTER=Character` in the messages.properties file I tried:

```
<label th:for="${{elementType}}"  th:text="#{label.pages.sorting.${{elementType}}}">Elem Types</label>
```

which does not work since the `${{elementType}}` is not evaluated inside the `#{...}`.

How can I make this work? Or is there another/better way to introduce localization of enum?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The following works:

```
<label th:for="${{elementType}}"  th:text="#{'label.pages.sorting.'+${{elementType}}}">Elem Types</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life))

Comment: Very good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to adapt the answer of @user1583209 to the following to make it work:

```
<label th:for="${elementType}"  th:text="#{'label.pages.sorting.'+${elementType}}">Elem Types</label>
```

Note the `{` and `}` instead of `{{` and `}}`.